# "The value of the field speed is the average speed in knots" adding values

Tags: java

Okay so I'm new to programming and I was wondering how to print values of certain fields. For example I have a speed and it's in knots (21 knots) how do I add the "knots" part to my code so I don't just print the integer? I want it to have [number] knots. 
This is the code I have so far:

```
public class Ship {
   //fields
   private String name;
   private double speed;

   //constructors
   public Ship(String n, double s) {
      name = n;
      speed = s;
   }

   //methods
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public double getSpeed()   {
      return speed; //avg speed in knots
   }

   public double timeTravel(double distance) {
      double travel = speed * 1.151;
      return distance;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change :

```
public double getSpeed()   {
      return speed; //avg speed in knots
   }
```

to:

```
  public String getSpeed()   {
          return speed+" knots"; 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Ship ship_object = new Ship();
String speed = ship_object.getSpeed() + ' knots';
System.out.println(speed);
```

See, if that helps.